# Symfony ORM Ilike DQL function Metadata Driver error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

In symfony 4.4 I try to create ilike dql function. Because it's not possible to use `ILIKE` in query builder. Only `LIKE` with `LOWER`. But it's not possible to use index with `LIKE` and `LOWER`.

I found some example of DQL function:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: client
    entity_managers:
        client:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            auto_mapping: true
            connection: dbalclient
            mappings:
                Client:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Client'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Client'
                    alias: Client
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    ILike: App\DQL\ILike
        vente:
```

Here, this is my function:

```
namespace App\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class ILike extends FunctionNode
{
    public $field;
    public $value;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return $sqlWalker->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->getILikeExpression(
            $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->field),
            $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticExpression($this->value)
        );
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->field = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->value = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

In my controller, I call my function in my query builder:

```
        $clientRepository = $this->emc->getRepository(Client::class);
        /** @var ORMQueryBuilder */
        $searchQuery = $clientRepository->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $searchQuery->select('partial c.{id}');
            if (isset($name)) {
                $searchQuery->andWhere('ILIKE(c.name, :name)');
                $searchQuery->setParameter('name', '%'.addslashes($nom).'%');
            }
```

I get this error:

> It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver and pass it to Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl(). (500 Internal Server Error)